# ASP.NET site opening from server produces error

Tags: asp.net, frontpage-extensions

I have a site that is running on a Windows Server 2008 machine with IIS 7.0, when I try to open it with Visual Web Developer 2010, it says the following:

error: unable to open site: ... The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed.

Looking on the server Frontpage Extensions 2002 are installed, so what could be wrong?

The thing is, I used to be able to open the project and work on it, etc...

Open Website -> Remote Site -> Enter remote site name -> tries to open & error above!

Can anybody assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [WebDAV](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/359/how-to-migrate-fpse-sites-to-webdav/), it is becoming the new standard for publishing content to web servers.

Microsoft isn't even going to support Front Page Extensions with IIS 7.5 so it's probably best to get on board with WebDAV as soon as you can.

Also, check out: [Installing and Configuring WebDAV on IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis-7/) for help with installations.